# Is there any calendar app which allows to sync Google and Outlook calendars?

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, kde5, google-calendar

On Windows 10 there is very useful and handy default mail application, which gives me possibility to sync to my google accounts and one outlook calendar into a single calendar view.

[image: screenshot of Calendar application in Windows]

I want to find a Linux app that can do this and will work well in the KDE environment. I am using Kubuntu 18.04 and Evolution Mail client.

Ideally I'm looking for a Qt-based app with a simple UI, without a hundred buttons and panels.

Answer (score 1):

The KDE project now has [Kalendar](http://apps.kde.org/kalendar) which can sync Google Calendar and others.